# Wpf : Drag Items With Adorner between two windows using c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have search most of the stuff but there is no way i found to drag the textblock item from one window to another window with Adorner (that is textblock item's name should be visible while dragging from one window to another window) in wpf.

Any Kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Even if you haven't found any tutorial or such, you can still try to implement something. Why, if you have one, did your current solution not work, and what have you tried up to this point?

Comment: I would suggest starting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144799%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Russ, i have tried the link u sent but i want to perform drag drop across two windows. in a single window i am able to do.